# Code signing error after updating iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, code-signing

I have just updated to iOS 6.1 from 6, (i kept putting it off a while back) I have been developing on my iPhone and now close to publishing - but all of a sudden when I run it xCode gives this error:

[image: The error]

I have checked and all my code signings are the same on the account and my phone is still authorised.

And here is the project file: Notice the MintfestProfile error:

[image: Proj]

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Check the profile status in the Organizer->Devices to check for valid profiles. Trying removing the profile from this window and reinstalling.

Comment: @rakmoh hey thanks for the comment! In there is says: "Valid signing identity not found" If i reinstall should it work?

Comment: It usually means that your certificate is either expired or missing. Can you check that?

Comment: @rakmoh it expires next year and its in my keychain

Comment: There are some bugs in Xcode handling of profiles. So try deleting the profile from XCode and readding it.

Comment: Even though the certificate is in your keychain, do you have the actual key-pair? That is, does the certificate have a disclosure arrow on the left that expands downward to show a key?

Answer (score 0):

Your Certificates and Provisioning Profiles have different exportation dates.

- Update any expired Certificates or Provisioning Profile
- Delete old profile in Xcode Organizer and Refresh (bottom right button)
- Reselect profile in build setting.

**Certificates**
[image]

**Provisioning Profiles**
[image]